# Повторение слова в предложении со вставной конструкцией

Tags: пунктуация

На сайте http://readr.ru/ditmar-rozental-spravochnik-po-russkomu-yaziku-punktuaciya.html?page=42

есть книга Розенталя, где есть такой пример:
…Встал Максим-то против дедушки – а дед ему по плечи, – встал и говорит… (М.Г.) – играет роль повторение слова встал (ср. § 40, п. 2);

на сайте http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_russkomu_jazyku_punktuacija/p7.php 
где размещена тоже книга Розенталя (другого издания?), приводится следующий пример:

Прежде чем мы расстанемся, — а некоторые из нас вернутся сюда, быть может, не скоро,— прежде чем мы расстанемся, я хотел бы ещё раз вернуться к только что сказанным словам о нашей дружбе — играет роль повторение слов прежде чем мы расстанемся.

почему здесь запятая есть и до первого тире?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь как раз тот случай, что иногда запятую и тире ставят для симметрии, для усиления паузы, там дальше есть примечание. Такой двойной знак часто ставили в 19 веке, когда больших строгостей в пунктуации не было.

Comment: Спасибо. А если в современном тексте поставить запятую для симметрии, причем она окажется между подлежащим и сказуемым, это будет ошибкой (или даже грубой ошибкой)?

Comment: запятой между подлежащим и сказуемым быть не может, только тире. Это грубейшая ошибка